# Connection Reset by [IP] Port 443 when trying to use SSH over HTTP connection

Tags: git, github, ssh, https

need help with a problem with Github.
I have been using jenkins to deloy my code automatically from Github. in which I've been using SSH for the authentication.
it works great until recently my company network dept decide to close port 22 for SSH,
which made my connection to Github failed in timeout.
[image: port 22 connection timeout]

been reading a lot of workaround, and it seems I can use SSH over HTTPS port by creating config file for my ssh connection. So I did by creating this config:

```
Host github.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
Port 443
User git
```

my git successfuly listening to port 443, but it came with a different issue:
[image: port closed by ip]

been looking information about this issue and most of it saying that the reason for port closed by [ip] error are because my IP was blacklisted by the host, in this case Github. which I don't think that would be the case.
do anyone have any info regarding what might be causing this?

and then, the workaround that a lot of people use is to add Github public key to my server known_hosts. I tried it but it doesn't work. do anybody knows the workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using https URL just like @VonC recommended.
it works on my server but not on my jenkins.

so I use personal access code instead, you can found the tutorial on how to create a personal access token [personal access token tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

then you can set up your repo url like this:

```
https://<access token>@github.com/<userName>/<repository>.git
```

it works for now, so I will close this thread. will update if there any solution from my network admin.

thanks.

Comment: That should work indeed, even though having the PAT in the URL is not a best practice (best to register it in Jenkins credentials)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried it but it doesn't work

It depends what you have added.

Try and add the output of `ssh-keyscan ssh.github.com`

Comment: hello, I already add the ssh-keyscan ssh.github.com to my known_hosts, and the result is my second screenshoot, Connection reset by [IP] port 443

Comment: @oRoberto Did you, for testing, try an HTTPS URL instead of an SSH?

Comment: can you elaborate?do you mean I should try to pull or fetch from github by using https url instead of SSH? if so, right now I still can't connect to github by using SSH authentication anyway. so I haven't tried it

Comment: @oRoberto Yes, the idea is to check if a clone using an `https://github.com/<me>/<myrepo>` URL would work.

Comment: hi, I've tried it and certainly I can clone by using HTTPS. but when I tried it on my jenkins it wouldn't work. so I found another workaround and will post it on different post. thank you for your help